# Open Windows Explorer with network location requiring credentials

Tags: c#, winforms, credentials, process.start

Could anyone please advise? I want my winforms app to open a network location. The network location is password protected etc, but that should be left for the user to enter as normal.

I tried this but explorer just opens at the default page (my computer).

```
Process.Start("Explorer.exe", @"/select,""" + "\\\\SomeLocation\\c$\\SomeDir\\" 
 + "\"");
```

I also tried this but it raises an exception:

```
Process.Start("\\\\SomeLocation\\c$\\SomeDir\\");
```

I got this error

```
'The specified network password is not correct'
```

I don't want network credentials to be a part of the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
Process.Start("explorer.exe", @"\\m3\c$");
```

Note sure if you should pass a subdirectory.

Comment: I think this would work (as might the attempts I posted) if the network location did not require a un/password. The result of this code is that explorer opens in the My Documents folder.

Comment: I have checked with a server I am not logged on to and it came up that I should login - meaning the normal credentials screen comes up. Maybe it is OS-dependend how explorer.exe works this out. My test is Win7 64bit.

Comment: Interesting. I am using Windows 8 64 bit. Thanks for the info.